# Can't open external hdd

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I could not mount my external harddrive to transfer all my files

```
`Error mounting /dev/sdc2 at /media/lucas/UUI: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdc2" "/media/lucas/UUI"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your system is missing the `mount.exfat` utility, which is provided by the `exfat-fuse` package. You can install it from the Software Center, or from a terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse
```

Comment: Damn, it seemed to be working but I have this unmet dependency which has been plaguing me for ever! I'll need to get that fixed first. Cheers for the help